# Where can I find computer modern fonts for use in other programs, e.g. Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: fonts, computer-modern, illustrator

For some complicated diagrams, I need to use something like Adobe Illustrator or Inkscape, and would like to include nicely typeset labels. (I'm aware of post-processing solutions, such as pinlabel.) One way to do this is to use a closely-matching font, and then convert fonts to outlines. Better, however, would be to use Computer Modern directly in Illustrator.

**Where can I find a Computer Modern font compatible with Adobe Illustrator?**

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can download them here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/cm-unicode/

Comment: @DanielEgberg: Could you please elucidate how I would install the tar.xz file?

Comment: @LePressentiment Use 7-zip to unzip it, there are .ttf files inside

Comment: How do you install these fonts into Libreoffice?

Comment: I downloaded this (onto a Mac) and used the installer XY.pkg that it came with.  Then opened Adobe Illustrator.  Not present.  Any suggestions?

Comment: This repository seems to be not official (info says TrueType converted by Andrey V. Panov from TeX fonts). Therefore I ran into scaling issues when importing .WMF's with encoded above TrueType fonts in Inkscape. Please download official TrueType Computer Modern fonts here https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cm/ps-type1/bakoma/ttf/ which do work legitimately (thanks @godbyk).

Comment: On a Debian based system (and maybe other Linuxes as well) it is recommendable to install these fonts from the repositories like suggested in the answer by @einpoklum. This also makes the fonts available to LibreOffice in a quite simple way.

Answer (score 12):

Also, Latin Modern is available in OpenType format from [GUST](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern).

Comment: Latin Modern also provides all web font formats i.e. .woff, .eot, .svg, which can be found here: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/foundry/gust-e-foundry

Answer (score 9):

They are available in [TrueType](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cm/ps-type1/bakoma/ttf/) and [OpenType](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cm/ps-type1/bakoma/otf/) formats through the BaKoMa distribution.

Comment: @Unfortunately, the aforesaid links beget a page saying that "Service Temporarily Unavailable".

Comment: @LePressentiment, It looks like ctan.org is down at the moment. You can try the following links to a CTAN mirror: [TrueType](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/fonts/cm/ps-type1/bakoma/ttf/) and [OpenType](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/fonts/cm/ps-type1/bakoma/otf/).

Answer (score 4):

What I do is to use [LaTeXiT](http://www.chachatelier.fr/latexit/) to generate labels as outlined fonts and drag them into the illustrator image. This works for both equations and text, and it's completely consistent with the TeX typesetting in your normal LaTeX file.

Answer (score 3):

Also see these [type 1](http://www.ams.org/publications/type1-fonts) fonts by the AMS.

Comment: Could you please elucidate where to download?

Answer (score 2):

On Debian-based systems (including Ubuntu, Mint and so on), OpenType versions of the Computer Modern fonts are available via the [`fonts-cmu`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/fonts/fonts-cmu) packages. Typically you would be able to install this by running

```
[joeuser@myhost]$ sudo apt-get install fonts-cmu
```

in a shell session.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some details to get Daniel Egeberg's answer to work on MacOSX:

Once you download the fonts from http://sourceforge.net/projects/cm-unicode/, unzip and place the individual files (not the folder) in Library/Fonts. Once you restart illustrator, the font will show as "CMU Serif", not as "Computer Modern".

More details:
https://www.adobe.com/products/type/install-instructions.html#macOS

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Firestar-Reimu/AMSFonts-OTF

Here is a OTF version converted by FontForge