# TeX fonts in Windows

Tags: fonts, opentype, type1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find computer modern fonts for use in other programs, e.g. Adobe Illustrator?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55/where-can-i-find-computer-modern-fonts-for-use-in-other-programs-e-g-adobe-ill)

I want to use TeX fonts in OpenOffice or Word, because there are many so beautiful fonts in Tex.
Can I use standard TeX fonts in Windows? What are standard math fonts in LaTeX?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) This question is very similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55/where-can-i-find-computer-modern-fonts-for-use-in-other-programs-e-g-adobe-ill. Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.(Btw it wasn't me who downvoted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is only possible for fonts in OpenType or Type 1. Copy such files, eg `lmroman*` into the
system fonts directory. Math fonts can only be used as OpenType, like Latin Modern or the commercial Lucida (http://www.tug.org/lucida).