# What's the font used in the environment align and packages amsmath, amsfonts?

Tags: fonts

What's the font of mathematical formulas (used in the environment `align` and packages `amsmath`, `amsfonts`) called, please? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Oh, those are Computer Modern. But I'm sure this does not answer your question. Maybe you're interested in [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919/5764)

Comment: I'm trying to plot a diagram in Omnigraffle, or word, or powerpoint. For this Computer Modern, unfortunately I couldn't find it from these softwares. Could you please tell me more explicitly about how to find them in, like, microsoft word? Thanks.

Comment: Mmmm, including fonts from LaTeX in software other than LaTeX? Sounds off-topic. You should look for the fonts inside the TeX Directory Structure (TDS).

Comment: There is an OpenType version of Computer Modern, link in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8308/make-ms-word-document-look-like-it-has-been-typeset-in-latex/8338#8338), if you install that you should be able to use the font in e.g. Word. Edit: Latin Modern, which is quite similar, also has an Open Type version: http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern

Comment: You should download Latin Modern Math too because the MSWord (2007 or later) Equation Editor can use that instead of the default Cambria Math.

Answer (score 2):

There is an OpenType version of Computer Modern, the default font used by TeX, available at http://sourceforge.net/projects/cm-unicode/ (see [Where can I find computer modern fonts for use in other programs, e.g. Adobe Illustrator?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55/where-can-i-find-computer-modern-fonts-for-use-in-other-programs-e-g-adobe-ill)).

Another font to be considered is Latin Modern, which is based on CM. It also has an OpenType math font that can be used by the equation editor in Word 2007 and later.

- [Latin Modern](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern)
- [Latin Modern math](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/lm-math/index_html)

Comment: I was searching for the web fonts for Computer Modern. On the links provided there only appears to be the OpenType font, but you can get the web fonts free from here: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/foundry/gust-e-foundry