# Recognize LaTeX font in Inkscape

Tags: fonts, matlab, inkscape

I am using the Latex interpreter for the figures, which I create and save as a .eps-file in matlab. The problem is that I want to change some names of the labels of the axis in these .eps files and I don't have any more the original .fig file or my original matlab-code/-data from which I have created these .eps-files.

If I open the .eps files with Inkscape, it doesn't recognize the font of the x- and y-labels and the legend. It just recognize the numbers on the x- and y-tick.
Is there any way to recognize the fonts in the .eps-file and change the names of the labels?

Thank you very much.

Comment: By it doesn't recognize, do you mean they are not imported into Inkscape? Btw. this seems to be off-topic in this forum. You probably should ask in a forum which is graphics related.

Comment: see for example https://answers.launchpad.net/inkscape/+question/285124 https://askubuntu.com/questions/307158/use-cm-roman-latex-font-in-inkscape and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55/where-can-i-find-computer-modern-fonts-for-use-in-other-programs-e-g-adobe-ill

Comment: And welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: Thank you very much.

With "doesn't recognize" I mean that the letters from the x- and y-labels don't have any font Information. If I click on them, they are treated like normal vector graphic objects with several nodes, which I can edit. But my goal is that Inkscape recognize the font with the font Information so that I can use the Text-Editor in Inkscape.

Comment: Note that with Inkscape there is an option to export to LaTeX code which doesn't need to know the font being used in the LaTeX document (which results in consistent fonts regardless of which fonts you use). But for working on the existent file you should install the fonts needed (as linked in the other comments).