# Recognize fonts

Tags: matlab, inkscape

I am using the Latex interpreter for the figures, which I create and save as a .eps-file in matlab. The problem is that I want to change some names of the labels of the axis in these .eps files and I don't have any more the original .fig file or my original matlab-code/-data from which I have created these .eps-files.
If I open the .eps files with Inkscape, it doesn't recognize the font of the x- and y-labels and the legend. It just recognize the numbers on the x- and y-tick. Is there any way to recognize the fonts in the .eps-file and change the names of the labels?

The problem is that the .eps doesn't seem to have any font Information of the y- and x-labels. If I want to edit them in Inkscape, they are just objects with nodes:

[image]

Thank you very much.

Comment: It's not clear what to me what it is that you've done. What does it mean to use "the Latex interpreter for the figures"? It sounds like you've created some figures in matlab and now want to edit them in Inkscape. Does your problem have any connection to LaTeX?

Comment: You asked this question yesterday https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375441/recognize-latex-font-in-inkscape and it got closed as a duplicate. You haven't added any new information. If closing the other one was a mistake, you should have said so rather than reask the question with nothing new.