# Is it possible to install the fonts used by LaTeX onto my computer?

Tags: fonts, pdf, standalone

The reason I ask is because I'm trying to take the standalones, update them with some variations using a graphic design software (Affinity Designer), and turn them into YouTube videos.

I could increase the size of the standalones (I think), but that would take a bit more work than if I were able to simply install the fonts, which would give cleaner results when resized.

Without the fonts installed, when I open the PDF file in a vector graphics editor, it comes up blurry when it's resized.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Here there are the links: https://www.checkmyworking.com/cm-web-fonts/ or here https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/computer-modern

Comment: I think that your question is similar to this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55/where-can-i-find-computer-modern-fonts-for-use-in-other-programs-e-g-adobe-ill

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find computer modern fonts for use in other programs, e.g. Adobe Illustrator?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55/where-can-i-find-computer-modern-fonts-for-use-in-other-programs-e-g-adobe-ill)