# How do I tell what is the default font for \texttt (default computer modern font, pdfLaTex)

Tags: fonts

I have a default latex document, and I use the \texttt to indicate a well-known or important repository or API function. I want to know what font type is \texttt using. I see that [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55/where-can-i-find-computer-modern-fonts-for-use-in-other-programs-e-g-adobe-ill) supposedly contains the answer (according to other closed questions), but I'm not sure how that linked post shows what the texttt font is. Below see an example of the font in roughly correct size.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\texttt{\expandafter\meaning\the\font}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

with pdflatex and

[image]

with lualatex

If you have loaded additional packages you may see other fonts